# String split by regex : {1-10} in java

Tags: java

expr: {1-5}

expr: {1-10}

expr: {1-100}

**I have tried with**

String arr[] = expr.replaceAll("\s+", "").split("(?<=[-+*/()])|(?=[-+*/()])");

**Result expr: {1-5}**

Element : {1

Element : -

Element : 5}

**Result expr: {1-10}**

Element : {1

Element : -

Element : 10}

**Result expr: {1-100}**

Element : {1

Element : -

Element : 100}

**I need this outcome:**

Element : {

Element : 1

Element : -

Element : 5

Element : }

How to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're trying to solve a different problem. Can you explain why you need to split the string like that?
You could easily extract the digits as fiels if you want with:

```
        final String[] split = a.replace("{", "").replace("}", "").split("\\-");
```